# How can I move image files to a folder?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on a ReactJS web app. I'm trying to upload a images to a folder and store the filename in the database so I can work with it.

Everything works so far, but my only blockade is the file transfer to the folder.

Here the ImageUpload component:

```
    import * as React from 'react';

   export class ImageUpload extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props : any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { file: '', imagePreviewUrl: '' };
    }

    _handleSubmit(e : any) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // TODO: do something with -> this.state.file
        alert(this.state.file.name);
        this.state.file.copy("C:\\Documents");
    }

    _handleImageChange(e : any) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let reader = new FileReader();
        let file = e.target.files[0];

        reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState({
                file: file,
                imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
            });
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }

    render() {
        let { imagePreviewUrl } = this.state;
        let $imagePreview = null;
        if (imagePreviewUrl) {
            $imagePreview = (<img src={imagePreviewUrl} />);
        } else {
            $imagePreview = (<div className="previewText">Please select an Image for Preview</div>);
        }

        return (
            <div className="previewComponent">
                <form onSubmit={(e) => this._handleSubmit(e)}>
                    <input className="fileInput"
                        type="file"
                        onChange={(e) => this._handleImageChange(e)} />
                    <button className="submitButton"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={(e) => this._handleSubmit(e)}>Upload Image</button>
                </form>
                <div className="imgPreview">
                    {$imagePreview}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to copy or move the file to **C:\Documents**. I didn't manage to find the solution to properly move the file to the folder.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you will have to handle the file upload and move on the server

Comment: So it is not possible to do the moving in react?

Comment: It's not possible to move files on the client, as far as I know. I'm assuming you're using ASP.NET as your backend server. You can upload the files and move them using ASP.NET

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload an image and save it to database, you need an API which will accept FormData, see [Form Data Usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), then on the server you will need to save that file to destination. For that you could use [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) and middleware to handle [multipart upload](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) - from there you can use NodeJS functions to save file to local destination.

It's not possible to do using only react.

Comment: Do you have an example for a request with my state.file?

Comment: You would need to append the `e.target.files[0];` to the `FormData` instance within your component / on the submit event. See Form Data Usage link from the answer.